# \subfile expands robust commands (so differs from \input in that respect)

Tags: input, subfiles, robust-commands

I'm overloading `_` as a non-breakable dash in nonmath, and this poses no problem with `\input`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\let\subscr=_
\catcode`_=\active
\DeclareRobustCommand_{\ifmmode\subscr\else\babelhyphen{nobreak}\fi}
\begin{document}
a_b ; \input{a_b.tex}
\end{document}
```

With an empty file `a_b.tex`, this compiles fine.

Changing `\input` for `\subfile`, however, creates an error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\let\subscr=_
\catcode`_=\active
\DeclareRobustCommand_{\ifmmode\subscr\else\babelhyphen{nobreak}\fi}
\begin{document}
a_b ; \subfile{a_ab.tex}
\end{document}
```

This triggers:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\filename@simple #1.\\->\edef \filename@base 
                                             {#1}
l.8 a_b ; \subfile{a_ab.tex}
```

A workaround that doesn't require to modify usage of `\subfile{}` is to restore the catcode of `_` temporarily:

```
% In preamble:
\makeatletter
\let\@sf=\subfile
\let\@sfs=\subfiles@subfile
\renewcommand\subfile{\catcode`_=8\@sf}
\def\subfiles@subfile#1{\catcode`_=\active\@sfs{#1}}
\makeatother
```

For reference, this is the code of the Subfiles package that is changed:

```
\newcommand\subfile{%
  \let\subfiles@loadfile\subimport
  \subfiles@subfile
}
\def\subfiles@subfile#1{%
  \begingroup
  \subfiles@handleSubDocument
  \subfiles@split{#1}%
  \subfiles@loadfile{\filename@area}{\filename@base}%
  \endgroup
}
```

*Question:* Is there a cleaner solution that would have `\subfile` parse its argument in a similar fashion as `\input`?  Would it be pushing it to call this a bug of `subfiles`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a 'raw' `\edef` inside the `subfiles` code, rather than using a `\protected@edef`. The LaTeX robust mechanism only works with `\protected@edef` and friends. At the same time, we need to provide a definition for `_` that can work inside file name: that can be done using `\ifincsname` (for technical reasons):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\subscr=_
\catcode`_=\active
\protected\def_{\ifincsname\string_\else
  \ifmmode\subscr\else\babelhyphen{nobreak}\fi\fi}
\begin{document}
a_b ; \subfile{a_ab.tex}
\end{document}
```

gives the expected error on my system: the file `a_ab.tex` is not found.

Comment: That's grand! Do you suggest the first part be reported upstream? As for the incsname thingy, I thought that since 2020, robust commands weren't expanded anymore. Is that a fix for older versions only, or something more profound? (In particular, using `include` instead of `input` doesn't work since the filename is repeated unprotected in `a_ab.aux`)

Comment: @Michaël At present we still have a `csname` expansion internally, which doesn't respect `\protected`. I wondered about that before: your example suggests it might want addressing. I've raise with the team.